# Does Animal Crossing: New Horizons have an offensive words filter for the island name?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In the Bridge chatroom, today we had a discussion on whether Animal Crossing: New Horizons would allow the name "Tardanas" (a name that was randomly generated by one of the online name generators) because the name contains an offensive word. Some of us think that the "no offensive words please" message on the name entry screen is just a "scouts honor" thing, but I personally think that it might be blocked, because even though you can only play with friends, there is still the reality of livestreaming and let's plays where these names might show up and Nintendo does not want that kind of publicity.

Does the game have an offensive words filter for the island name?

Comment: what's the offensive word in "Tardanas"?

Comment: @AaronF "Tard" is a somewhat common abbreviation of "retard", a mental health slur.

Comment: oh, I see. Is that a USA-only thing? (And it's not even a word!)

Comment: @AaronF Yeah, it's mostly an Americanism. It used to be a legitimate description for those with a mental disability in English psychology and other mental health circles. However, it fell out use as such in the 1960s because people started using the term as insult.

Comment: @Nzall : if they search for any *substring* in the name which might itself be a substring of something potentially offensive, then lots of [legitimate words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) would be banned or replaced for [hilarious results](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-). And users would find ways to insult each other with legitimate words which are not offensive by themselves (["I want to stick my long-necked Giraffe up your fluffy white bunny"](https://tinyurl.com/mc3gc6)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User discussion of the game online seems to indicate that it does *not*, or at least that it isn't an especially robust filter:

> [image: ![A screenshot of Tom Nook saying to the player, "Splendid! Then, from now on, this island will be known as *horsecock*.]

(Image source: https://twitter.com/cacodemonfan/status/1240859064487141379)

The tweet in question also has replies featuring others' screenshots of names one would expect a language filter to catch.

Answer (score -6):

It is for sure locked. Nintendo doesn’t mess around on these since this word can be seen online.

EDIT: For a good 20 years now Nintendo has had a 'bad word filter' for any first party
game that asks you to put in text. So it would not be a big jump to assume that there is one in Animal Crossing too.